# how to add a silverlight page in asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, silverlight-4.0

I want a aspx page that has Silverlight page embed in it, so that if I click any button in aspx page some text will be printed in the text box of Silverlight page.

for this what type of Silverlight  template should we choose that are in Visual Studio 2010 and I am using Silverlight 4.

Please provide me step by step procedure for embedding Silverlight into aspx page.

Please friends help me and I am thankful for the answer.

Thanks in Advance
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

You can embed Silverlight component into asp.net web page via HTML `<object>` element or JavaScript - `Silverlight.js` helper script.

For more information read:

1. [Integrating Silverlight with a Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838145%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
2. [Encapsulate Silverlight with ASP.NET Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135987.aspx)